# How do I retrieve the public key from a SSH private key?

Tags: command-line, ssh

A SSH private key as generated by `ssh-keygen` contains a public key part. How do I retrieve this public key from the private key? I've lost my public key and need to put the contents of this public key in the servers `authorized_keys` file and do not want to create a new key pair.

Alternatively phrased: how do I create the `id_rsa.pub` file from a `id_rsa` file?

Comment: `pbcopy > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` oops.

Comment: @NickT - pbcopy is a MacOSX command. Plus, it's useless if you've rebooted, logged out, or copied anything else to the clipboard.

Comment: @NickT `command not found: pbcopy` oops.

Answer (score 879, accepted):

I've found the answer on Server Fault: *[Create a public SSH key from the private key?](https://serverfault.com/q/52285/51929)*

The [option `-y`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) outputs the public key:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

As a side note, the comment of the public key is lost. I've had a site which required the comment (Launchpad?), so you need to edit `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and append a comment to the first line with a space between the comment and key data. An example public key is shown truncated below.

```
ssh-rsa AAAA..../VqDjtS5 ubuntu@ubuntu
```

For keys that were added to the SSH Agent (a program that runs in the background and avoids the need for re-entering the keyfile passphrase over and over again), you can use the `ssh-add -L` command to list the public keys for keys that were added to the agent (via `ssh-add -l`). This is useful when the SSH key is stored on a smart card (and access to the private key file is not possible).

Comment: Please note that your private key file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` must be restricted to your username. use `$ sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and enter your root credentials to restrict it, then you can output the public key file. Otherwise you will get unrestricted private key file warning.

Comment: @MarkMikofski No need for `sudo`, you are supposed to own the private key already. Otherwise you cannot read it in the first place.

Comment: @Lekensteyn thanks, of course you're right!. Also `400` is recommended since no need to write to type private key file.  Corrected command should be `$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Private key comment is lost. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290929/generate-public-ssh-key-from-private-key

Comment: @weberjn The private key (`id_rsa` file) does not have a comment, but indeed the comment within the public key file (`id_rsa.pub`) is lost.

Comment: $ ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa
4096 SHA256:WZDX3x8N+ZzUkIAOkibG34Y1SY6G1p8oqXmI1sOlIN8 your_email@example.com my comment (RSA)

Comment: you just saved my life :)

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!

Comment: It actually prints the comment of the private key. If the private-key has a comment set, it gets printed. See also [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ssh-key-comments#private-key-comments)

Answer (score 16):

*This is a solution is specifically for users using Windows to SSH into their remote machines, including cloud images on Amazon AWS and GCE.*

## (Disclaimer)

I recently used this solution to remote log in to new deployed VM images on GCE.

---

## Tools used:

1. [puttygen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html)
2. [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

---

## Steps to perform:

1. Generate a public/private key pair using puttygen.
2. Upload a public key to your server in the cloud or remote location.

---

## Description (how to do it):

1. Generate a key/pair or use an existing private key:

   **If you have a private key:**

   Open puttygen, press load button and select your private key (*.pem) file.

   **If you do *not* have a private key:**

   - Open puttygen,
   - Select the desired key type SSH2 DSA (you may use RSA or DSA) within the Parameters section... and it is important that you leave the passphrase field blank,
   - Press generate and follow instructions to generate (public/private) key pair.

   [image: Sample Key Generation pic]
2. Create a new 'authorized_keys' file (with Notepad):

   Copy your public key data from the "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file" section of the PuTTY Key Generator, and paste the key data to the "authorized_keys" file.

   Make sure there is only one line of text in this file.
3. Upload the key to a Linux server:

   - Open WinSCP,
   - Select the SFTP file protocol and log in with your SSH credentials.
   - On success, you see the home directory structure at your remote machine.

   Upload authorized_keys file to the home directory at the remote machine.
4. Set proper permissions:

   Make a `.ssh` directory (if it does not exist)

   Copy the `authorized_keys` file to the .ssh directory (this will replace any existing `authorized_keys` file; take note of this).

   If the file exists, simply add the contents of this file to the existing file.

   Run commands to set permissions:

   ```
    sudo chmod 700 .ssh && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

Now you will be able to ssh into a remote machine without entering credentials every time.

## Further reading:

1. *[Generating and uploading SSH keys under Windows](https://opengear.zendesk.com/entries/23216142-Generating-and-uploading-SSH-keys-under-Windows)*
2. *[Authentication without password using OpenSSH Key, certificates .pem and .pub](http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/server-administration/openssh-keys-certificates-authentication-pem-pub-crt)*

Comment: If Your home directory is encryted, do this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/439184/how-is-a-login-via-an-ssh-private-public-key-associated-with-a-given-user/700344#700344

Comment: although your answer is not really relevant to the question, I vote for it because of your enthusiasm.