# Best practices for .ssh? Should I be disabling all root login and user password access, period?

Tags: networking, permissions, ssh, password

I am new to this so please dumb this down a little for me.

I use OSX locally, Ubuntu server for my remote host on Linode. And to my understanding, I can use `ssh-keygen -b 4096` locally, to generate two files:

`~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

And then on my server I run `mkdir -p ~/.ssh && sudo chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh/` to create the .ssh folder and give it recursive read/write/execute privileges for the "file owner" (whatever that is, according to the chmod wiki).

Then I call

`scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub example_user@123.4.567.89:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Which I guess uses ssh protocol to upload the public key to the server in a newly-created `authorized_key` file in the server's `.ssh` folder I just created.

So I assume this means the public file goes on the server, whereas both the public and private file reside on my local machine.

Now let's say I edit my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file where I can mess with `PermitRootLogin`, `PasswordAuthentication`, and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`.

My questions:

1. Should I be disabling root login? Should I set `PermitRootLogin` to `no` or to `without-password`? Should I be disabling all passwords and using keys only, period? What about `PasswordAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`?
2. Is it safe to have the private and public key files on my local machine? Should I be deleting the public one and only holding onto the private one?
3. If I am only relying on the key, doesn't this mean I am now exposed to a new weakness: Someone getting into my machine and therefore getting access to my key file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best practice" with ssh, or any server for that matter, is to :

1. Assess the value of your asset and the data on your server where you install and configure ssh. Is this a home computer behind a lan ? Or a public ip address on a server with sensitive data, private information, financial information ? etc.
2. Read ALL the security options.
3. Then decide how you want to balance security with ease of access, ease of configuration, and value of your assets.

For my considerations on ssh see - http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security

Comment: But I am trying to understand the implications too. For instance what stops someone from making a new key pair and doing `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub example_user@123.4.567.89:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to overwrite the authorized keys? Does this no longer work if passwords are not allowed?

Comment: Are there other logins I should be disabling?

Comment: A user can not copy the key with scp or other methods if they can not log in.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to have the private and public key files on my local machine? Should I be deleting the public one and only holding onto the private one?

The public key can be derived from the private key (but not the other way around). [How do I retrieve the public key from a SSH private key?](https://askubuntu.com/q/53553/158442) The public key is provided merely as a matter of convenience so that you don't have to generate it every time you need to add your key to a new server.

> If I am only relying on the key, doesn't this mean I am now exposed to a new weakness: Someone getting into my machine and therefore getting access to my key file?

That's why you don't blindly press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when running `ssh-keygen` and instead use a strong password (of course, different from you user's password) to encrypt your key.

> Should I be disabling root login?

It's effectively disabled by default since the defaults only allow key-based login and root has not `authorized_keys` by default.

> Should I set `PermitRootLogin` to `no` or to `without-password`?

It's set to `without-password` because that's a safe default. You can set it to `no` if you so wish. However, if you ever need to `rsync`/`scp` as root, you'll run into trouble.

> Should I be disabling all passwords and using keys only, period? What about `PasswordAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`?

If you can stick with this policy, then certainly use keys only and disable both.

Comment: When you mention defaults, they are not true for me (at least when using linode). I don't know how to enforce key login only or what I should be setting these fields to.

Comment: Then you should complain to Linode. `PermitRooLogin without-password` is the default in Ubuntu (key-based). Also read `man sshd_config`.

Comment: If I set that to without-password what would I then set `PasswordAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to for safety? Both to `no`?